# "System.IO.StreamWriter" or "System.IO.StreamReader" code in VB.Net - How to find correct file paths?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, .net

I have a big problem, and that is my problem in all my applications.

My problem is:

In any of my applications, i got used the "System.IO.StreamWriter" or "System.IO.StreamRead" code, for example:

```
Dim WriterDay6 As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\IOSEagle\Desktop\My Projects\Microsoft Visual Basic 2010\Form\Programs\MyAlarm\MyAlarm\RepeatDays\Saturday.txt")
```

But this path does not exist in another computers.

So, any one help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration. This lists out various folders you can use, like the Desktop, Application Data, and My Documents folders.

In VB.Net, you can also look at `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories`.